# Can't open Jupyter Lab runing on local Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, jupyter-lab

I'm creating a course that will require students to run some software called PyStan. It turns out that this is [only partially supported on Windows](https://pystan2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/windows.html).

Someone gave me an idea to use Docker so that students wouldn't have any issue getting the software they need to do assignments. The end goal is that students can do very little to get Jupyter Lab up and running on their own machines, with as little effort as possible.

I tried writing the following to be run with `sudo docker compose up`

```
version: '3'
services:
  ubuntu_anaconda:
    image: continuumio/anaconda3:latest
    container_name: ubuntu_anaconda
    environment:
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - JUPYTER_TOKEN=my_secret_token  # Set your desired token here
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"  # Expose Jupyter Lab port
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data  # Add this line if you want to mount a local directory to the container
    command: /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install -y -c conda-forge pystan && /opt/conda/bin/jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --allow-root --NotebookApp.token=$${JUPYTER_TOKEN}"
```

However, when I open up a web browser and navigate to `http://localhost:8888/` or `http://localhost:8888/?token=my_secret_token` it says

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> - The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
> - If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer’s network connection.
> - If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the web.

On the other hand, when I navigate to https://127.0.0.1:8888/ it says

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8888.
> PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
>
> Error code: PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR
>
> - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
>   Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is docker-compose that works for me, it only requires create directory `./notebooks` with permission `777` or to be owner by user id `1000`

```yaml
version: "3.9"

services:
  jupyter:
    image: jupyter/scipy-notebook
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./notebooks:/home/jovyan/
    environment:
      JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB: "yes"
      JUPYTER_TOKEN: 1234
    command: bash -c "pip install pystan && start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token='${JUPYTER_TOKEN}'"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Root Cause

Seems your container is not reachable by some network setting... Not sure what happened, I would need to know your whole set up. Maybe or necessary just restart the pc and try the following steps.

## Solution

I tested your docker compose file on an ubuntu 24 host and it works fine. I started up the jupyter session as follows (I allowed root just because it is intended to be local and non production env):

```bash
docker compose up
docker exec -it <container_name> bash
jupyter notebook --allow-root
```

## Extra Ball

In your use case It maybe more intuitive with Visual Studio pluggings

1. Open the folder which contains the docker-compse.yml with Visual Studio
2. Click on `Add dev container configuration files`
   [image]
3. Click on `From docker-compose.yml` (it will detect your file)
   [image]
4. It will build the container and then attach to it.
   [image]
5. Open a terminal from visual studio and you will be ready to up the jupyter server and run whatever you or your students need in the server
   [image]

I hope this two insights help you! :)